# Show that $\ f_n$ converges uniformly to $f(z)=z$ knowing that $f_n(0)=0$ and $f'_n(0)>0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\{Ω_n\}_n$ be a sequence of simply connected domains with $0∈Ω_n⊂\mathbb{D}$. Having:

- $dist(0,∂Ω_n)\to1$ as $n\to∞$
- $f_n∈\mathcal{H}(\mathbb{D})$
- $f_n$ bijective over $Ω_n$
- $f_n(0)=0$ and $\ f'_n(0)>0$

Show that:
$$f_n \overset{\mathbb{D}}{\implies} f(z)=z$$

(This means uniform convergence over compacts of the disk).

**HINT**: prove first that $\lim_{n\to∞}f'_n(0)=1$

---

**What I've tried**:

I've tried to approach it using the Riemann application theorem, but that only gives me the existence of sequences of functions satisfying $\ f_n(Ω_n)=\mathbb{D}$. I also don't know how to prove the hint.

Any help?

Comment: Seems to be information missing. Otherwise, take $f_n(z) = nz$.

Comment: No. $f_n(z)=nz$ doesn't satisfy "$f_n$ bijective over $\Omega_n$.

Comment: But ...,    
what is the meaning of "$f_n$ bijective over $\Omega_n$ " ?  
$f_n : \Omega_n \to \Omega_n$ bijective ?  $f_n : \mathbb{D}\to \Omega_n$ bijective or others... ?

Comment: @ts375_zk26 bijective over $\Omega$ means $f_n:\Omega \to \Omega$ is bijective.

Comment: Then $f_n^\prime(0)=1$... Nothing to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n^\prime(0)=1...$ Something is wrong...

Comment: @ts375_zk26 I don't understand your last comment.

Answer (score 1):

The following result contains your result: Suppose for $n=1,2,\dots$ that $f_n\in H(\mathbb D), f_n(0) = 0,$ $f_n'(0)>0.$ Assume further that there are sequences $r_n,s_n \to 1^-$ such that $f_n$ is 1-1 on $D(0,r_n)$ and $D(0,s_n)\subset f(D(0,r_n)) \subset \mathbb D$ for all $n.$ Then $f_n(z) \to z$ uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb D.$

Sketch: 1. It's enough to show there is a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ which does the above.

2. Suppose $f$ is holomorphic and 1-1 on $D(0,r)$ with $f(0)=0.$ If $r,s > 0$ and $D(0,s)\subset f(D(0,r)),$ then $|f'(0)|\ge s/r.$
3. Normal families argument.

Comment: I don't understand why $|f'(0)| ≥ s/r$ in point 2. of the sketch. Can you explain it please?

Comment: We have $f^{-1}: D(0,s) \to D(0,r).$ Let $g(z) = f^{-1}(sz)/r.$ Then $g: \mathbb D \to \mathbb D$ with $g(0)=0.$ By the Schwarz Lemma, $|g'(0)| \le 1.$ This gives the result.

Comment: in point 2. I see that $\{f_n\}$ is a normal family since it is uniformly bounded at $\mathbb{D}$. So there exists a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ which converges uniformly over compacts to $f$. We then have $f'(0)=1$, and by Schwarz lemma in the equality version, I can show $f(z)=e^{iθ}z$. And since I know $f'(0)=e^{iθ} > 0$, $f$ must be $f(z)=z$.
This last argument seems a little bit awkward for me, is it ok?

Comment: I meant point 3.